# Using block() on Mono<Foo> always fails

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a function that works on a single element:

```
Mono<Foo> myFunction(String arg) {
  // do shiz
  return result;
}
```

Now, I am trying to reuse the above method to do the same, but for a list of args:

```
Mono<List<Foo>> myNewFunction(List<String> args) {
  Flux.fromIterable(args)
    .map(currentArg -> myFunction(currentArg))
    .map(Mono::block)
    .collectList();
}
```

But it always fails with the same error:

```
ava.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3
...
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.xxx.yyy.zzz.Controller#foo(InputRequest) [DispatcherHandler]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/v1/my/end/point" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

(A controller is calling the `myNewFunction`)

I have verified that `myFunction` works when I call it directly from the controller. But when I go through `myNewFunction`, it fails.

How do I debug this and fix this? I can't tell what the error is.
Thanks

Comment: Well... don't call `block`? Instead of returning `Mono<List<Foo>>` you could instead return a `Flux<Foo>`, I guess.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. I just tried it, but then when my controller returns `ResponseEntity<Flux<Mono<Foo>>>`, the actual reponse I see in Postman is `"scanAvailable": true`

Comment: Are you familiar with `flatMap`? You could rewrite this as `Flux.fromIterable(args).flatMap(this::myFunction)` (depending on where both of your methods are). This should result in `Flux<Foo>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Flux` is an asynchronous sequence of 0-N items, while `Mono` end with 0-1 result, so your controller shoud return `Flux<Foo>`:

```java
Flux<Foo> myNewFunction(List<String> args) {
  return Flux.fromIterable(args)
    // if myFunction returns Mono, use flatMap instead of map.
    .flatMap(currentArg -> myFunction(currentArg));
}
```

If you want return `Mono<List<Foo>>` instead of `Flux<Foo>`, use `collectList`:

```java
Mono<List<Foo>> myNewFunction(List<String> args) {
  return Flux.fromIterable(args)
    .flatMap(currentArg -> myFunction(currentArg))
    .collectList();
}
```

Second, blocking operation should not used in non-blocking thread, which cause the error.